# Isn't an Int64 equal to a long in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, long-integer, int64, int32

I have been playing around with SQL and databases in C# via [SqlCeConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I have been using [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read results and [BigInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) values for record IDs which are read into Longs.

Today I have been playing with SQL statements that use COUNT based statements ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X') and have been using [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to read these single valued results.

However, I ran into an issue. I can't seem to store the values into a Long data type, which I have been using up to now. I can store them into Int64's.

I have been using BigInt for record IDs to get the maximum potential number of records.

A BigInt 8 bytes therefore is an Int64. Isn't a Long equal to an Int64 as both are 64-bit signed integers?

Therefore, why can't I cast an Int64 into a Long?

```
long recordCount =0;

recordCount = (long)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

The error is:

> Specified cast is not valid.

I can read a BigInt into a Long. It is not a problem.
I can't read an SQL COUNT into a long.

COUNT returns an Int (Int32), so the problem is in fact casting an Int32 into a long.

Comment: What is recordCount defined as?

Comment: @BoltClock: You *can* directly cast `int` to `long` (in fact you don't even need a cast because there's an implicit conversion available). The OP's problem is that you can't unbox a boxed `int` to a `long`. Boxed value-types (generally) need to be unboxed to exactly the same type.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`long` is `Int64` [in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx); it is just an alias in C#. Your problem is casting the return value to `long` and unless we know the type coming back from your query for sure, we would not know why you get an error. SQL BigInt must be convertable to `long`.

If it is the COUNT(*) which is coming back, then it is Int32. You need to use the [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
long l = Convert.ToInt64(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: +1, You're right that `COUNT` returns a 32-bit integer, and I'm pretty sure that this is the source of the OP's problem when they try to unbox that `int` to a `long`. There's no need for the explicit `Convert.ToInt64` though: `long l = query.ExecuteScalar();` will work just fine since an `int` is implicitly assignable to a `long`.

Comment: Yes, that will make sense, I will try finding a similar question that Jon Skeet had replied a few days ago.

Comment: `long l = query.ExecuteScalar()` will fail at compile time as you cannot convert implicitly an object to a long. Similarly, `long l = (long)query.ExecuteScalar()` fails at runtime as this cast is not valid. Using `Convert.ToInt64` converts the object to Int64, or long.

Comment: @anothershrubery: Oops, you're right: `long l = (int)query.ExecuteScalar();` will do the trick though (although I'm not sure whether it's more readable than using `Convert.ToInt64` or not).

Comment: @Aliostad I can store a BigInt into a long no problem I cant store the COUNT result as a long I get  {"Specified cast is not valid."}, however, I can cast into a int64 which should be the same as a long?

Comment: @andicrook: The result of `COUNT` is an `INT`, not a `BIGINT`, and I bet that you can't unbox it to an `Int64` or a `long` (since they're *exactly* the same type). If you're convinced that you can then please show us *(1)* the exact working code, and *(2)* the exact broken code.

Comment: @andicrook: To store it in a `long`/`Int64` variable then you need to either do `long l = Convert.ToInt64(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());` as in Aliostad's answer above, or `long l = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();`.

Comment: @LukeH  your right COUNT returns a Int (Int32) so the problem is in fact casting a Int32 into a long.

Answer (score 6):

If you're thinking that your counts are going to overflow an int/Int32, you ought to use [COUNT_BIG()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx) in your SQL instead - it has the correct return type.

---

As to why the casts aren't working, I'm not sure. The following C#:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
long lCount = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Int64 iCount = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Compiles to this IL:

```
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: newobj instance void [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand::.ctor()
L_0006: stloc.0 
L_0007: ldloc.0 
L_0008: callvirt instance object [System.Data]System.Data.Common.DbCommand::ExecuteScalar()
L_000d: unbox.any int64
L_0012: stloc.1 
L_0013: ldloc.0 
L_0014: callvirt instance object [System.Data]System.Data.Common.DbCommand::ExecuteScalar()
L_0019: unbox.any int64
L_001e: stloc.2 
L_001f: ret
```

That is, they appear to compile to identical code.

Comment: COUNT_BIG() doesnt cast into a long either. COUNT and COUNT_BIG will cast into a int64 but not into a long when a long is a int64 why?

Comment: @andicrook - could you decompile your code to IL for the long and Int64 versions, as I've done above, and add your results to the question?

Comment: My fault i didn't recompile still didn't work i dont think COUNT_BIG is supported by SQL Compact Edition {"The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact Edition. [ Name of function = COUNT_BIG,Data type (if known) =  ]"}

Comment: @andicrook - the return type of `COUNT()` is int/Int32, so storing it in an int/Int64 isn't gaining you anything. You're right that compact doesn't support `COUNT_BIG()`, but I think this is the first time you've mentioned that that's your target SQL Server.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever  I did specify i was using compact edition I said via SqlCeConnection (Ce = compact edition) not SqlConnection. You right i didnt realise the limitation of COUNT therefore I cant get the benefits from a int64 or long anyway. Need to look up the maximum records per table for this edition as well and possibly drop everything to int32. However, i will be adding support for full SQL server later so its good to know about COUNT_BIG. Thanks