# Why is Int64.MaxValue a long?

Tags: c#

[image]

Shouldn't it be an integer type instead?

This way, some functions which are using int fail to accept this as an argument, since it returns a long but they expect an int

Comment: simply because Int64 == long

Comment: int64 IS a long. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260314/c-sharp-isnt-a-int64-equal-to-a-long

Comment: `long` is synonym of `Int64`. `int` is synonym of `Int32`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In .NET there are common **built-in** type aliases for all primitive and some standardized types. Each alias corresponds to an actual .NET type, and both the alias and the type name can be used interchangeably.

Here is a list some of the aliases in C#. Other .NET languages, might use different aliases for the same types (like is the case with VB.NET)

```
    byte   -> System.Byte
    short  -> System.Int16
    int    -> System.Int32
    long   -> System.Int64
    string -> System.String
    ...
```

As you can see, `System.Int64` represents a 64-bit integer a.k.a. a `long`.

Comment: Not particular to C#. VB.NET has the same.

Comment: Oh, ok..  It being called Int64 threw me off

Comment: @MattWilko Not exactly, the aliases in VB are different. For instance you have `Integer`, not `int`. I have mentioned the C# specific ones.

Comment: My point was that your answer inferred that C# was the only language to have aliases, but your answer as it stands now clears that up.

Comment: @MattWilko, excuse me for the delayed reply. Yes, you are correct in the context of the early version of my post and that is why I edited it, so thanks for noticing. I must admit I find it hard to write a shiny post from the first time, but gladly there is the wiki edit capability.

Comment: Today I learned something

Answer (score 7):

`Int64` is a `long` type.

`Int32` is an `int` type.

Comment: `long long` is a phrase that does not appear in the C# specification, so I'm not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: @aakashm me neither, thx, edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

.NET uses type aliases for certain types. This means that the type alias is the exact equivalent of it's relative value type. As you can see from the list below, the type alias for System.Int64 is "long". Here is the full list of type aliases in .NET.

```
//Alias      |  Relative Data Type
byte         |  System.Byte
sbyte        |  System.SByte
short        |  System.Int16
ushort       |  System.UInt16
int          |  System.Int32
uint         |  System.UInt32
long         |  System.Int64
ulong        |  System.UInt64
float        |  System.Single
double       |  System.Double
decimal      |  System.Decimal
string       |  System.String
bool         |  System.Boolean
object       |  System.Object
```

Comment: "In .NET, primitive types are just short-cuts to their equivalent structures" - do you perhaps mean "In C#, some datatype keywords are exactly equivalent to certain `System` value types" ?

Answer (score 1):

> Long == Int64 >>Output: True
>
> Int == Int32 >>Output: True
>
> Int64 == Int32 >>Output: False

You can only convert a Long/Int64 to an Int/Int32 if it is small enough but you can always convert an Int to a Long. Int64/Long supports numbers larger and smaller than the standard Int.