# In C# What's the difference between Int64 and long?

Tags: c#, long-integer

In C#, what is the difference between Int64 and long?

Example:

```
long x = 123;
Int64 x = 123;
```

Comment: They're the same, just like string and String

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260314/isnt-an-int64-equal-to-a-long-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 31):

There is no difference in the compiled code. They are aliases for the same thing.