# Cast double to long change the value

Tags: c#, type-conversion, double

I have noticed that the conversion from `double` to `long` *changes the value* when the number to be converted is *large*, even if it is well below the *max value* of a `long`.
For example, does someone can explain me why this conversion *does not work as expected*:

```
Convert.ToInt64(600000000000040000d)
// Return => 600000000000039936
Convert.ToInt64(600000000000040000L)
// Return => 600000000000040000
```

This cause some trouble in my formulas...
Thanks.

Comment: From [the documentation for `double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.8): " A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision". You are using 19 digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `double` has *mantissa* of `52` bits *only* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format for details); that's why `double` can represent *precise* integer values up to `2**53 - 1 == 9007199254740991`. However,

```
 600000000000040000 > 9007199254740991
```

that's why *rounding errors* are inevitable:

```
  double d = 600000000000040000d;

  long l = (long)d;

  double d2 = l;

  Console.WriteLine($"{d:r} : {l} : ({d == d2 ? "Equal" : "Different"})");
```

Outcome:

```
  6.0000000000004E+17 : 600000000000039936 : Equal
```

You can try `decimal` instead of `double` (esp. if you are working with financial data):

```
  decimal d = 600000000000040000m; // m suffix

  long l = (long)d;

  decimal d2 = l;

  Console.WriteLine($"{d} : {l} : ({d == d2 ? "Equal" : "Different"})");
```

Outcome:

```
  600000000000040000 : 600000000000040000 : Equal
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Decimal resolved my problem but, more important, I understand the reason of this behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps :

> When you convert a double or float value to an integral type, this value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If the resulting integral value is outside the range of the destination type, the result depends on the overflow checking context. In a checked context, an OverflowException is thrown, while in an unchecked context, the result is an unspecified value of the destination type.

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table

Note: Long is an integral type it is Int64: [In C# What's the difference between Int64 and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876660/in-c-sharp-whats-the-difference-between-int64-and-long?lq=1)

Additionally, float and double are types with floating-point. They are stored in memory differently 
[How are floating point numbers stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644699/how-are-floating-point-numbers-stored-in-memory)

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you more.

```
// Double to long
           double av = 600000000000040000L;
            long lg = (long)av;
            long g1 = Convert.ToInt64(av);
// long to Double
            double dbl = (double)g1;
            double d = Convert.ToDouble(g1);
```